# AcmNotPossible calling acmStreamOpen Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, naudio

In my application i have some Audio files those are in **.wav** Format, Here i am checking Each audio file **BitRate** , and if any file in below 128Kbps,i changed those files bit rate to 128kbps,by using Below code

```
int bitrate;
string FullPath = @Server.MapPath("~/AudioFiles/");
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(FullPath, "*.wav", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; i++)
{
    string[] FileExt = filePaths[i].Split('\\');
    string[] Ext = FileExt[FileExt.Length - 1].Split('.');
    string ExtFile = Ext[Ext.Length - 1];
    if (ExtFile == "wav" || ExtFile == "WAV")
    {
        using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(filePaths[i]))
        {
            bitrate = reader.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond * 8;
            reader.Dispose();
        }
        if (bitrate < 128000)
        {
            using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(filePaths[i]))
            {
                var newFormat = new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1);
                using (var conversionStream = new WaveFormatConversionStream(newFormat, reader))
                {
                    WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(Server.MapPath("~/AudioFiles/" + FileExt[FileExt.Length - 1]), conversionStream);
                }
            }
    }
}
```

the above code is working for most of the files, But i get below error for some audio files.[image]
 how can i solve the issue?

Comment: Please pick the correct language tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can typically only change one thing at a time with ACM, so if you have a 16kHz stereo file, you can't go to an 8kHz mono file in one go.

So you need to see what `WaveFormat` your `WaveFileReader` has, and possibly do multiple conversion steps.

It may also be that your input WAV file is using a codec that ACM can't decode. But again you'd need to examine your input `WaveFormat` to know that.