# AcmNotPossible calling acmStreamOpen when I try to convert .WAV file to MP3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, wav, naudio

In this situation, I'm trying to get the URI of a .WAV audio that is stored in Azure Storage. Here is the service code snippet:

```
var tempAudioUrl = _blobStorareService.UploadFileToBlob(file.FileName, file.ReadFully(), file.ContentType);
            var audioFile = await AudioConverter.ConvertToMp3Async(new Uri(string.Format(tempAudioUrl)));

            var audioUrl = _blobStorareService.UploadFileToBlob(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), audioFile, "audio/mp3");

            _blobStorareService.DeleteBlobData(tempAudioUrl);
```

The code of the AudioConverter class:

```
public static class AudioConverter
{
    public static async Task<byte[]> ConvertToMp3Async(Uri uri)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var file = await client.DownloadDataTaskAsync(uri);
            var target = new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1);
            using (var outPutStream = new MemoryStream())
            using (var waveStream = new WaveFileReader(new MemoryStream(file)))
            using (var conversionStream = new WaveFormatConversionStream(target, waveStream))
            using (var writer = new LameMP3FileWriter(outPutStream, conversionStream.WaveFormat, 32, null))
            {
                conversionStream.CopyTo(writer);

                return outPutStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone knows the answer I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you use `WaveFormatConversionStream` , you should use `RawSourceWaveStream` first. It can help you solve the issue.

Reason:  [if you have a 16kHz stereo file, you can't go to an 8kHz mono file in one go.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40023808/7687666)

**Related Post:**

[AcmNotPossible calling acmStreamOpen, naudio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13641288/7687666)